# Coolant Level Drop

Tags: vw, coolant, coolant-leak

I have a 2013 VW CC 2.0 TSI. I have noticed a slight and continuous drop in the Coolant Level within the expansion tank, unfortunately no trace is found on the floor. I happened to go underneath the car and found red liquid around the Engine Oil Bottom pan. It appears when the engine has cooled down. I was able to fully inspect the water pump and no leaks were found. I need a rescue please!![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWjeI.png)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!